# "Error in the Site Data Web Service." when performing crawl

Tags: sharepoint, search, search-server

Installed SharePoint Services v3 (SP2, october 2009 cumulative updates, Language Pack), attached to a content database I had previously (all works). Installed Search server 2008 Express (with language pack) on top of WSS and **crawl does not work**. However it works for newly created web application + database.

Was playing around with accounts, permissions to try get it working. Currently I have WSS_Crawler account with such permissions:

- Office Search Server runs with WSS_Crawler account
- Config database has read permissions for WSS_Crawler
- Content database has read permissions for WSS_Crawler
- WSS_Crawler is owner of search database.
- Added WSS_Crawler to SQL server browser user group and administrator

Yes, i'v given more permissions than needed, but it doesn't even work with that and i don't know if its permission problem or what.

Crawl log says there is *Error in the Site Data Web Service.*, nothing more. There were [known issues with a similar error](http://vspug.com/lovedjohnysmith/2009/07/08/error-in-the-site-data-web-service-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range/): `Error in the Site Data Web Service. (Value does not fall within the expected range.)`, but this is not the case as thats an old issue and i hope it has been included in SP2...

Logs are from olders to newest (descending order). They don't appear to be very helpful.

## Crawl log

- http://serveris Crawled Local Office
  SharePoint Server sites 3/15/2010
  9:39 AM
- sts3://serveris Crawled Local Office
  SharePoint Server sites 3/15/2010
  9:39 AM
- sts3://serveris/contentdbid={55180cfa-9d2d-46e4...
  Crawled Local Office SharePoint
  Server sites 3/15/2010 9:39 AM
- http://serveris/test Error in the
  Site Data Web Service. Local Office
  SharePoint Server sites 3/15/2010
  9:39 AM
- http://serveris Error in the Site
  Data Web Service. Local Office
  SharePoint Server sites 3/15/2010
  9:39 AM

## EventLog

No errors in EventLog, just some Information events that Office Server Search provides

- The search service started.
- Successfully stored the application
  configuration registry snapshot in
  the database.  Context: Application
  'SharedServices
- Component: da1288b2-4109-4219-8c0c-3a22802eb842
  Catalog: Portal_Content. A master merge was started due to an external request.
- Component: da1288b2-4109-4219-8c0c-3a22802eb842
  A master merge has completed for catalog Portal_Content.
- Component: da1288b2-4109-4219-8c0c-3a22802eb842
  Catalog: AnchorProject. A master merge was started due to an external request.
- Component: da1288b2-4109-4219-8c0c-3a22802eb842
  A master merge has completed for catalog AnchorProject.

## ULS Log

Just some information, but no exceptions, unexpected errors

```
03/15/2010 09:03:28.28  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x0E8C  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Insert crawl 771 to inprogress queue hr 0x00000000 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:6591   
03/15/2010 09:03:28.28  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x0E8C  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Request Start Crawl 1, project Portal_Content, crawl 771 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:2875     
03/15/2010 09:03:28.28  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x0E8C  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 1, project Portal_Content, crawl 771 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853    
03/15/2010 09:03:28.28  w3wp.exe (0x1D98)                           0x0958  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        8wn6    Information A full crawl was started on 'Local Office SharePoint Server sites' by BALTICOVO\janis.veinbergs.     
03/15/2010 09:03:28.43  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x10F8  ULS Logging                     Unified Logging Service         8wsv    High        ULS Init Completed (mssdmn.exe, Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll)  
03/15/2010 09:03:30.48  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x09C0  Search Server Common            MS Search Indexing              8z0v    Medium      Create CCache    
03/15/2010 09:03:30.56  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x09C0  Search Server Common            MS Search Indexing              8z0z    Medium      Create CUserCatalogCache     
03/15/2010 09:03:32.06  w3wp.exe (0x1D98)                           0x0958  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        90ge    Medium      SQL: dbo.proc_MSS_PropagationGetQueryServers     
03/15/2010 09:03:32.09  w3wp.exe (0x1D98)                           0x0958  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        7phq    High        GetProtocolConfigHelper failed in GetNotesInterface().   
03/15/2010 09:03:34.26  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x16A4  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 12, project Portal_Content, crawl -1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853    
03/15/2010 09:03:35.92  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x16A4  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 12, project Portal_Content, crawl -1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853    
03/15/2010 09:03:37.32  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x16A4  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 12, project Portal_Content, crawl -1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853    
03/15/2010 09:03:37.23  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x1850  Search Server Common            MS Search Indexing              8z14    Medium      Test TRACE (NULL):(null), (NULL)(null), (CrLf):  , end   
03/15/2010 09:03:39.04  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x16A4  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 12, project Portal_Content, crawl -1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853    
03/15/2010 09:03:40.98  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x0B24  Search Server Common            MS Search Indexing              7how    Monitorable GetWebDefaultPage fail. error 2147755542, strWebUrl http://serveris  
03/15/2010 09:03:41.87  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x1260  Search Server Common            PHSts                           0   Monitorable CSTS3Accessor::GetSubWebListItemAccessURL GetAccessURL failed: Return error to caller, hr=80042616 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3acc.cxx Line:505  
03/15/2010 09:03:41.87  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x1260  Search Server Common            PHSts                           0   Monitorable CSTS3Accessor::Init: GetSubWebListItemAccessURL failed. Return error to caller, hr=80042616 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3acc.cxx Line:348     
03/15/2010 09:03:41.87  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x1260  Search Server Common            PHSts                           0   Monitorable CSTS3Accessor::Init fails, Url sts3://serveris/siteurl=test/siteid={390611b2-55f3-4a99-8600-778727177a28}/weburl=/webid={fb0e4bff-65d5-4ded-98d5-fd099456962b}, hr=80042616 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3handler.cxx Line:243     
03/15/2010 09:03:41.87  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x1260  Search Server Common            PHSts                           0   Monitorable CSTS3Handler::CreateAccessorExB: Return error to caller, hr=80042616 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3handler.cxx Line:261    
03/15/2010 09:03:40.98  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x1260  Search Server Common            MS Search Indexing              7how    Monitorable GetWebDefaultPage fail. error 2147755542, strWebUrl http://serveris/test     
03/15/2010 09:03:41.90  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x0B24  Search Server Common            PHSts                           0   Monitorable CSTS3Accessor::GetSubWebListItemAccessURL GetAccessURL failed: Return error to caller, hr=80042616 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3acc.cxx Line:505  
03/15/2010 09:03:41.90  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x0B24  Search Server Common            PHSts                           0   Monitorable CSTS3Accessor::Init: GetSubWebListItemAccessURL failed. Return error to caller, hr=80042616 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3acc.cxx Line:348     
03/15/2010 09:03:41.90  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x0B24  Search Server Common            PHSts                           0   Monitorable CSTS3Accessor::Init fails, Url sts3://serveris/siteurl=/siteid={505443fa-ef12-4f1e-a04b-d5450c939b78}/weburl=/webid={c5a4f8aa-9561-4527-9e1a-b3c23200f11c}, hr=80042616 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3handler.cxx Line:243     
03/15/2010 09:03:41.90  mssdmn.exe (0x1750)                         0x0B24  Search Server Common            PHSts                           0   Monitorable CSTS3Handler::CreateAccessorExB: Return error to caller, hr=80042616 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3handler.cxx Line:261    
03/15/2010 09:03:43.26  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x0750  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 24, project Portal_Content, crawl 771 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853   
03/15/2010 09:03:43.26  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1804  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Remove crawl 771 from inprogress queue - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:6722   
03/15/2010 09:03:43.26  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x0750  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 12, project Portal_Content, crawl -1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853    
03/15/2010 09:03:44.65  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1804  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Insert crawl 772 to inprogress queue hr 0x00000000 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:6591   
03/15/2010 09:03:44.65  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1804  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Request Start Crawl 0, project AnchorProject, crawl 772 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:2875  
03/15/2010 09:03:44.65  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1804  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 0, project AnchorProject, crawl 772 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853     
03/15/2010 09:03:44.65  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1804  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Unlock Queue, project Portal_Content - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:2922     
03/15/2010 09:03:44.82  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1DD0  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 0 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:44.95  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x0750  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 12, project AnchorProject, crawl -1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853     
03/15/2010 09:03:46.51  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x0750  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 12, project AnchorProject, crawl -1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853     
03/15/2010 09:03:46.39  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1E4C  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 0 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:49.01  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1C6C  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:49.87  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x155C  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:49.29  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x155C  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:49.53  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x155C  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:49.67  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x155C  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:49.82  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x155C  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:49.84  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x155C  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 0 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:49.89  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x155C  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 0 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:49.90  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x0750  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 12, project AnchorProject, crawl -1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853     
03/15/2010 09:03:51.42  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1E4C  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 4, project AnchorProject, crawl 772 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853     
03/15/2010 09:03:51.00  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1E4C  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 0 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:51.42  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1CCC  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Remove crawl 772 from inprogress queue - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:6722   
03/15/2010 09:03:52.96  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1CCC  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Insert crawl 773 to inprogress queue hr 0x00000000 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:6591   
03/15/2010 09:03:52.96  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1CCC  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Request Start Crawl 0, project AnchorProject, crawl 773 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:2875  
03/15/2010 09:03:55.29  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1CCC  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Unlock Queue, project AnchorProject - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:2922  
03/15/2010 09:03:55.29  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1CCC  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Removed start crawl request from Queue 0, crawl 773  - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:2942     
03/15/2010 09:03:55.29  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1CCC  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Request Start Crawl 0, project AnchorProject, crawl 773 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:2875  
03/15/2010 09:03:55.29  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1CCC  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 0, project AnchorProject, crawl 773 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853     
03/15/2010 09:03:55.37  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1CCC  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 0 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:55.37  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x0750  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 12, project AnchorProject, crawl -1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853     
03/15/2010 09:03:56.71  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1E4C  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 0 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:56.78  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x0750  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 12, project AnchorProject, crawl -1 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853     
03/15/2010 09:03:58.40  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x155C  Search Server Common            GathererSql                     0   Monitorable CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal Flush anchor, count 0 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4943   
03/15/2010 09:03:58.89  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x155C  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Advise status change 4, project AnchorProject, crawl 773 - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:4853     
03/15/2010 09:03:58.89  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1130  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Remove crawl 773 from inprogress queue - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:6722   
03/15/2010 09:03:58.89  mssearch.exe (0x1B2C)                       0x1130  Search Server Common            GatherStatus                    0   Monitorable Unlock Queue, project AnchorProject - File:d:\office\source\search\search\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx Line:2922
```

What could be wrong here - any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a problem if your UserInfo table in the database has corrupted SIDs in it. I could definitely see this happening if you attached an existing content db rather than doing backup/restore. The way to test/fix it is:

1. Run the following command against your content database in SQL Server:

   Select tp_login, tp_systemid, tp_deleted from userinfo where len(ltrim(rtrim(tp_systemid))) <25 and tp_deleted = 0
2. For any users returned by the query (except for system users), give the user read permission at the root of the site collection. (System users include: `NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users, NT AUTHORITY\local service, NT AUTHORITY\system, SHAREPOINT\system`
3. Rerun the query to make sure it has no results; when there are no results, start a full crawl.

[Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dorong/archive/2009/09/24/error-in-the-site-data-web-service-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range.aspx) is a blog post that talks about this solution.

Comment: Yes, i`v tried that already, but that query only returns nt authority\local service and sharepoint\system user for me.

I deleted local service from site collection then, but couldn't do that with sharepoint\system.

Ofcourse, rerunning the query, i would still get that system user...

Comment: Also, a solution mentioned doing -export and -import is not suitable for production environment, as it will not preserve Modified and Modified By fields :(

Comment: @Janis Veinbergs: it is OK if you still get the system user (and local service actually) so corrupt SIDs are clearly not your problem. Unfortunately the only other solution I can think of is recreating the site collection with export/import.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. Found that the sites were not opening from the index server. The web.config was corrupted with duplicate entries. Cleaning this up resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting, the search started to work... i don't know what caused the problem. The important thing is that it works!